# Capturing a java NoClassDefFoundError thrown by program called via shell script

Tags: java, shell, unix

I have a java program which is a compiler and executor for Jasper Reports and is called via shell script on our reports server.

I just fixed a bug caused by a missing dependancy, but it took me a while to figure out what was going wrong. Normally, problems caused by the compile process are captured, recorded to a log file and emailed to the relevant person. As this was a NoClassDefFoundError, it basically exited the program and failed in a silent manner from the users perspective.

Is there any way for me to capture errors like this one so that they can also be emailed away? I have the authority to modify the executing shell script.

Comment: http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/java/sending-email-using-apache-log4j

Comment: I looked into log4j a bit, but from my understanding I dont think that would work. A NoClassDefFoundError cannot be captured inside the program to be logged as it force exits immediately.

Comment: in your static main method in your start class you could include a try ... catch (Throwable) ... which will be able to handle the noclassdeferror

Comment: Ahh silly me, catch Throwable is what I was after... Ive never had to use a higher level than Exception, so never really thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically errors are not caught by application code and are thrown to JVM level where they are printed to STDERR. So, your way to track this error is to redirect STDERR to file:

`java -cp YourMain 1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log`

You can also put both STDOUT and STDERR together:

`java -cp YourMain 1>&2 2>wholelog.log`

There is a lot of reference about stream redirection in web. You can take a look there if my examples do not satisfy you. And it a depends on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Just can catch the error i.e.

```
try {
        numericDefinition = new net.sf.cb2xml.def.BasicNumericDefinition(
                    binName, binarySizes, SynchronizeAt, usePositive, floatSynchronize, doubleSynchronize
            );
} catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

You do need to be very careful of your coding though, it is easy to get **NoClassDefFoundError** thrown at class initialisation time and not get into to the try .. catch block.

The **NoClassDefFoundError** will be thrown the first time a class is refereneced which could be when could when a class uses a class which uses a class  which uses a class ... which uses a class that references a class that does not exist.

The following may fail with **NoClassDefFoundError** at class initialization because of the import.

```
import net.sf.cb2xml.def.BasicNumericDefinition; // could cause the NoClassDefFoundError

     ...........
 try {
            numericDefinition = new BasicNumericDefinition(
                        binName, binarySizes, SynchronizeAt, usePositive, floatSynchronize, doubleSynchronize
                );
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```